# teracotta client server reconnection

Tags: terracotta

I am running a single instance of terracotta server 3.7.5 with two java clients.

I have few questions related to this configuration.

1) If Teracotta Server goes down I want to receive an exception in clients. Is it possible ?

2) If Teraacotta server comes back up I want these clinet to reconnect to server.

I have came across this URL http://terracotta.org/documentation/4.0/terracotta-server-array/high-availability

I am not sure if these configs are vaild for open source 3.7.5

Regards,
Amber

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

1) If Teracotta Server goes down I want to receive an exception in clients. Is it possible ?
A: You can use Nonstop Caching caching for this .
http://terracotta.org/documentation/3.7.4/enterprise-ehcache/reference-guide#nonstop

Use

2) If Terracotta server comes back up I want these clinet to reconnect to server.
A: You can use Rejoin for this along with NonStop. 
http://terracotta.org/documentation/3.7.4/enterprise-ehcache/reference-guide#71266